# Linux system call invocation for x86

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, system-calls, qemu

I am trying to understand the way system-calls are invoked on a Linux machine. For this, I ran a guest machine with a [Linux 3.0.43 kernel](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0.43/) on the QEMU emulator.

In order to know the system call numbers, I instrumented the interrupt function in qemu (`do_interrupt_all()` in `target-i386/seg_helper.c` --- not very important). Basically whenever I get an int 0x80 interrupt, I print the value in the EAX register. The output of the run gave the system call numbers. I expected the exec system call for the init process first. Then a fork and some `brk system calls. However, I am not sure if that is what I got. I am printing the first 100 system call numbers here. My guest is a 64-bit machine. [Here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0.43/) is an online code exploration for my kernel.

```
 : 11
 : 45
 : 33
 : 192
 : 33
 : 5
 : 197
 : 192
 : 6
 : 33
 : 5
 : 3
 : 197
 : 192
 : 192
 : 192
 : 6
 : 192
 : 243
 : 125
 : 125
 : 125
 : 91
 : 122
 : 45
 : 45
 : 197
 : 5
 : 5
 : 5
 : 5
 : 221
 : 141
 : 141
 : 6
 : 5
 : 5
 : 5
 : 5
 : 5
 : 197
 : 192
 : 3
 : 3
 : 6
 : 91
 : 5
 : 197
 : 192
 : 3
 : 3
 : 6
 : 91
 : 5
 : 197
 : 192
 : 3
 : 3
 : 6
 : 91
 : 5
 : 197
 : 192
 : 3
 : 3
 : 6
 : 91
 : 5
 : 197
 : 192
 : 3
 : 3
 : 6
 : 91
 : 5
 : 197
 : 192
 : 3
 : 3
 : 6
 : 91
 : 5
 : 5
 : 197
 : 192
 : 3
 : 3
 : 6
 : 91
 : 5
 : 197
 : 192
 : 3
 : 3
 : 6
 : 91
 : 5
 : 197
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's what you got ([Linux System Call Numbers](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html), [64-bit Linux System Call Numbers](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/linux_syscalls_64bit.html)):

- 11 : `sys_exevce`, or `exec`'s system call
- 45 : `sys_brk`, the thing under malloc
- 33 : `sys_access`
- 192 : `lgetxattr`

And so on.

Comment: One more thing ... what is the use of sys_access and lgetxattr system calls on booting ??

Comment: oh yeah ... I realized this later... My stupid mistake was to misread the line number on the syscall page  http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0.43/arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S for sytem-call number. The system call number is written on the right side. :)

Comment: @prathmesh.kallurkar: Hah. Well, hope all goes well for you.